# Pass scroll event data into throttle function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, throttling

I am trying to create my own simple full height scrolling script using the `wheel` event and a throttle function (as I only want 1 scroll to be registered every X milliseconds. I want to pass the event data of the `wheel` event into the function that is being throttled by my `throttle()` function.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
function throttle(callback, limit) {
    var wait = false; // Initially, we're not waiting
    return function () { // We return a throttled function
        if (!wait) { // If we're not waiting
            callback.call(); // Execute users function
            wait = true; // Prevent future invocations
            setTimeout(function () { // After a period of time
                wait = false; // And allow future invocations
            }, limit);
        }
    }
}

function onScroll(event) {
  // do stuff here on scroll
}

window.addEventListener('wheel', throttle(onScroll, 700), false);
```

This would work fine if I didn't need data from the `wheel` event, but I need to determine the scroll directions inside of my `onScroll()` function using `event.deltaY`.

Essentially I want to change the last line to the following (although I know this wouldn't work):

`window.addEventListener('wheel', throttle(onScroll(event), 700), false);`

**So...**

How can I pass the `wheel` event data into the `onScroll()` function whilst still throttling it?

**What I've tried:**

I tried the following code so that I could pass the `event` data into the `throttle()` function, which worked successfully

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  throttle(onScroll, 700, e)
}, false);
```

But I am then not sure what to do with `e` inside of my `throttle()` function to be able to pass it to the `onScroll()` function. I tried changing the line with:

`callback.call(); // Execute users function`

to:

`callback.call(e); // Execute users function` (using the `e` passed into the throttle function)

But that stopped the `onScroll` function from even being called... (I assume because `throttle()` is returning a function but this returned function isn't being called because it's wrapped inside another function in the `eventListener`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass through the arguments:

```
function throttle(callback, limit) {
  var wait = false;
  return function (...args) { 
    if (!wait) {
        callback(...args);
        wait = true; 
        setTimeout(function () { 
            wait = false; 
        }, limit);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what should the `window.addEventListener...` line look like?

Comment: @jj `window.addEventListener('wheel', throttle(onScroll, 700), false);`

Comment: How does that pass the event data into the onScroll function? And what exactly do I replace "...args" with? There is no event data passed through to `throttle()` with the code you wrote so there are no arguments to pass through...

Comment: @jj It does, ... `onScroll` will be called with the first argument being the event

Comment: Ah okay sorry I apologise, I have never come across `...args` before and so was confused by that, I'll accept your answer but it may be good to include the whole updated snippet + a link to an explanation of `...args` or something, thanks though! :)